# Unfair Gambler's Ruin problem

Tags: probability, statistics

Here is the problem I am currently working on:
[image: problem]

In (a), why do we care about $E[2^{W_t}]$ and $E[2^{W_{t+1}}]$? Why not just $E[W_{t+1}], E[W_t]$?

Comment: $E[W_{t+1}] \not = E[W_t]$ so that may be why it is not considered

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that (a) holds not only while you keep playing, but also after you've stopped playing because you won or lost. How does the probability of having stopped playing evolve over time? Given that you've stopped playing, what's $\mathbb E\left[2^{W_t}\right]$?